# Laravel MVC concept

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I am still used to MVC concept but i understand the basic concept of it.
I found this code on a "PHP" blog.

```
<?php
class Todo_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    public function action_list() {
        $todos = Todo::all();
        return View::make("list")
                ->with("todos", $todos);
    }

    public function action_view($id) {
        $todo = Todo::where_id($id)->first();
        return View::make("view")
                ->with("todo", $todo);
    }

    public function action_delete($id) {
        $todo = Todo::where_id($id)->first();
        $todo->delete();
        return View::make("deleted");
    }

    public function action_new() {
        return View::make("add");
    }

    public function action_add() {
        $todo = new Todo();
        $todo->title = Input::get("title");
        $todo->description = Input::get("description");
        $todo->save();
        return View::make("success");
    }
}
```

That is a controller but I notice **action_list(), action_view() and action_delete()** are running SQL but it is doing it in a **controller**. 
Why is that? shouldn't that be in the model? Isn't the purpose of a **model** to do anything data related?

The reason why I am asking this is because I have seen a lot of laravel tutorials both paid and unpaid ones doing this and I am asking myself, why mix the business logic with the data schema?

Comment: Most tutorials explain how to do something functional, like "How to save a Todo with Laravel". Quick and dirty. The context of the code above is probably for that purpose and not to teach you best practices software development.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the repository pattern to extract the data querying from your controller.

```
class TodoRepository {

    public function get_todo($id)
    {
        return Todo::find($id);
    }

    public function get_all_todos()
    {
        return Todo:all();
    }

    public function create_todo($todo)
    {
        return Todo::create([
            'title'  => $todo['title'],
            'description' => $todo['description']
        ]);
    }

    public function delete_todo($todo)
    {
        return Todo::find($todo)->delete();
    }
}
```

Then you inject the repository into your controller. That way if you change databases, or ditch eloquent then you just write a new repository with the same interface and you simply change out the injection.

```
class Todo_Controller extends Base_Controller
{
    private $todos;

    public function __construct(TodoRepository $todos)
    {
        $this->todos = $todos;
    }

    public function action_list() {
        return View::make("list")
                ->with("todos", $this->todos->get_all_todos());
    }

    public function action_view($id) {
        return View::make("view")
                ->with("todo", $this->todos->get_todo($id));
    }

    public function action_delete($id) {
        $this->todos->delete_todo($id);
        return View::make("deleted");
    }

    public function action_new() {
        return View::make("add");
    }

    public function action_add() {
        $todo = $this->todos->create_todo(Input->get('title', 'description');
        return View::make("success");
    }
}
```

This was your controller doesn't care how you get_all_todos or delete_todo, it simply asks the repository to get/modify the data then it returns the result.